# Save text files in S3 with same date as that of input parquet files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a few parquet files in S3 which are back dated (feb 2020) and i am processing them using spark scala (jar file via Data Pipeline) to save as text file. The problem is that when i process them, the files are getting saved with today's timestamp. I want to save them having same timestamp as the input file. I tried using -

```
  ds.coalesce(1)
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .text(destinationPath)
```

Comment: The file timestamp is not possible to be changed, this is related to S3 api, this is related to the how S3 works. What I recommend is use partitions to create folders with the day you want.

Comment: best way you can add new column say `last_update_ts` and update this every operation, so it's not dependent on any cloud platform time stamp